# Characterization of isometric embedding from low dimensional Euclidean spaces to high dimensions

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Let $m < n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let us equip $\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n $ with their canonical Euclidean (Riemannian) metrics. How can we characterize the isometric embeddings of $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n $? To be more precise, I'm looking for sufficiently regular, injective, distance preserving transformations from $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so that: $d_m(x, y)= d_n(\Phi(x), \Phi(y))$, where $d_m, d_n$ represents the distances in $m, n$ dimensional Euclidean spaces respectively, so e.g. $d_m(x,y):=||x-y||_{\mathbb{R}^m}$.

I think the answer is:

$$x \mapsto A(Bx, O(Bx))$$ where $A$ is an Euclidean isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. a rigid motion), $B$ is an Euclidean isometry of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (i.e. a rigid motion), and $O:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is "zero padding $n-m$" times, namely: $O(x)= (x, 0,\dots 0)$.

If the above correct/incorrect, how do I go about proving it or characterizing the Euclidean embeddings?

Comment: These embeddings are representable by a combination of $x \mapsto (x, 0,0,...,0)$ from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, combined with an isometry of $\Bbb R^n; v \mapsto b + Av$, for some constant $b \in \Bbb R^n$ and orthogonal matrix $A \in O(n)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks - I think you're right, I've to sit down and convince myself!

Comment: It isn't that hard to see: first note that the condition that $A$ is an isometry on $\Bbb R^n$ that fixes $0$ is exactly the requirement that $A$ is an orthogonal linear transformation of $\Bbb R^n$ (the parallelogram theorem is useful here). Then note that if $f$ is any isometry on $\Bbb R^n$, then $v \mapsto f(v) - f(0)$ is an isometry which fixes $0$. Finally note that for any isometric embedding of $\Bbb R^m$ in $\Bbb R^n$, there is an isometry of $\Bbb R^n$ which carries the image to $\Bbb R^m \times \{0\}^{n-m}$, and the inverse of an isometry is also an isometry.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry I just sat down and tried to understand your argument. I agree with everything, except one: what theorem are you using to guarantee that there exists an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that carries the image $\phi(\mathbb{R}^m)$ (Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an isometric embedding) onto $\mathbb{R}^m \times \{0\}^{n-m}$? I mean $\phi(\mathbb{R}^m)$ could be highly non linear subset/submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as we don't know if $\phi$ is linear or affine. In this case, how do you guarantee that such an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ exists?

Comment: @Mathmath Here's a hint: try proving first that an isometry of Euclidean space fixing the origin is linear.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356136/characterization-of-extrinsic-distance-prevserving-embedding-see-the-definition

Comment: Max is correct. All isometries of $\Bbb R^n$ are affine. Recognizing this starts with noting that three points $a, b, c$ are collinear with $b$ between $a$ and $c$ if and only $\|a - b\| + \|b - c\| = \|a - c\|$. Because of this, isometries can only carry lines to lines.